# Terraform azure import multiple subnets

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have my azure cloud setup manually. It almost has 5 subnets. Now in order to make it IAAS, I am writing a Terraform code  for it. I know, I can import resource by using the command "terraform import azurerm_subnet.mysybnet ". This only imports one subnet. How can I import multiple subnets? For example, if I have subnets with names "vm-subnet", "aks-subnet", "acr-subnet", "nsg-subnet" and "firewall-subnet". How can I import all these subnets in one shot?

My current code is

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  } 
}
    
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
    
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myrg" {
  name     = "myRG"
  location = "WEST US 2"
}
    
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myvnet" {
  name                = "myvnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myrg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.myrg.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
    
#Create subnets within the resource group
resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  name                 = "acr-subnet"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.myrg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.myvnet.name
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you currently have to the question.

Comment: To import multiple subnets, you need to create a Terraform resource block for each one and then write a shell script that executes Terraform import for each subnet. Terraform does not have a built-in way to import several resources at once with a single CLI command for any provider. @Sreehari

Comment: Ok! You mean I need to create subnets in a for_each and do import using a script?

Comment: Yes, Using for_each can also simplify the terraform configuration by creating multiple similar resources with single module..@Sreehari

Comment: @VinayB: Seems to be good idea. Can you share a sample code?

Comment: @Marko As suggested added the code.

Comment: @Sreehari Do you have other `address_prefixes` for the networks you want to import? If so, please add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of terraform you are using, you can now use `import` blocks with [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#import-multiple-instances-with-for_each), which works on the terraform versions >1.7.x. For example:

```
locals {
  subnets = {
    "acr-subnet"      = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
    "vm-subnet"       = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
    "aks-subnet"      = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
    "nsg-subnet"      = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
    "firewall-subnet" = ["10.0.4.0/24"]
  }
}

import {
  for_each = local.subnets
  to       = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[each.key]
  # populate the subscription ID with your value
  id       = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myvnet/subnets/${each.key}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each             = local.subnets
  name                 = each.key
  address_prefixes     = each.value
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.myrg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.myvnet.name
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad that Terraform has added import block. Small correction in your code. ${each.value} replace with ${each.key}

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to azure import multiple subnets into the state using terraform and shell scripts and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

A common requirement is to import multiple resources into a Terraform state at once. You have to import each resource individually.

The problem with your scenario is that `terraform import` only works for single resources. If you want to import multiple resources of the same kind (such as subnets), you have to run the import command multiple times, giving a different identifier for each resource in your Terraform configuration.

My preexisiting resources in portal

[image]

1. **Define the Terraform Configuration for Each Subnet**: Before importing, you must have a Terraform resource block for each subnet you wish to import.
2. **Use a Script to Automate the Import Process**: Write a shell script (or a script in another language) that runs `terraform import` for each subnet.

***My Terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "testrg-vk"
  location = "East US" # Change this to your actual location if different
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "testvkvnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "A map of subnets"
  type = map(object({
    address_prefixes = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "vm-subnet" = {
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
    },
    "aks-subnet" = {
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
    },
    "acr-subnet" = {
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
    },
    "nsg-subnet" = {
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
    },
    "firewall-subnet" = {
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.4.0/24"]
    },
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = each.key
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
}
```

***Shell script:***

```
# Define the subscription ID, resource group, and virtual network name
$SubscriptionId = "Subscription ID"
$ResourceGroup = "testrg-vk"
$VNetName = "testvkvnet"

# Subnet names and their corresponding CIDR notation
$subnets = @{
    "vm-subnet" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "aks-subnet" = "10.0.1.0/24"
    "acr-subnet" = "10.0.2.0/24"
    "nsg-subnet" = "10.0.3.0/24"
    "firewall-subnet" = "10.0.4.0/24"
}

# Loop through each subnet and import it
foreach ($subnet in $subnets.GetEnumerator()) {
    $subnetName = $subnet.Key
    $terraformResource = "azurerm_subnet.example[`"$subnetName`"]"
    $azureResourcePath = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$VNetName/subnets/$subnetName"
    terraform import $terraformResource $azureResourcePath
}
```

Before executing the command, make sure both files are in the same directory and follow the steps below.

***Step 1:***

Run the command **`terraform init`**

[image]

***Step 2:***

Now execute the commands

**`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`**

&

**`.\Import-Subnets.ps1`**

This commands will starts executing the commands inside the shell scripts.

***Output:***

[image]

This step is executed repeatedly until the given list is fully processed.

***Step3:***

Now run the command **`terraform state list`**

[image]